# php error Catchable fatal error al hacer consulta

Tags: php, mysql

tengo esta duda, probablemente sea muy sencilla su respuesta pero como tengo muy poco haciendo esto pues aun no me empapo bien de la lógica jejejeje. Bueno a la pregunta:

esta parte del codigo me marca el error:"Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"

```
 $queryjoin="SELECT matriculas.matricula from matriculas inner join aspirantes on matriculas.id_mat=aspirantes.id_asp where aspirantes.folio=$id;";
                     $n_control = mysqli_query($link,$queryjoin); echo $n_control;
```

pueden ayudarme? son dos tablas en una misma base, cuando lo corro en la consila de mysql si me da el resultado deseado pero aqui al hacer el echo $n_control; me marca ese error, ayuda por fa
en las tablas los valores son INT

Mil gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: @alanfcm muchisimas gracias, tienes razón, es algo muy básico pero estoy aprendiendo muchisimo en este foro, en unos dias más yo creo que publicaré un par de dudas que tengo, o espero que no jejejeje mil gracias, lo entendi perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable $n_control contiene un objeto de tipo mysqli_result.  Solo puedes usar echo para desplegar strings.  La forma que usualmente se hace es asi:

```
$queryjoin="SELECT matriculas.matricula from matriculas inner join aspirantes on matriculas.id_mat=aspirantes.id_asp where aspirantes.folio=$id;";
$n_control = mysqli_query($link,$queryjoin);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($n_control)) {
    echo $row['matricula'];
}
```